# Skip blank cells in spreadsheet

Tags: python

I have a `for` loop that pulls data from a spreadsheet on a website and writes the data to a text file.  It is common that the spread sheet is not updated and therefore blank.  When the spreadsheet is blank my loop fails.  How would I skip the loop in the event that it fails?

```
for row in aatable.findAll('tr')[1:]:
     items = row.text.replace(u"kn","") # remove kn so items line up when unpacking
     time, ais_source, speed_km, lat, lon, course = items.split()[1:7]
     data = items.split()[1:7]
     text_file.write(str(data)+ ",Adams Challenge"+'\n')
```

Comment: can you give an example of what `row.text` contains exactly normally and when it is 'blank'? Do you mean it would be an empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign `aatable.findAll('tr')` to a variable `data` and check `if data` to catch an empty list:

```
data = aatable.findAll('tr')
if data: # will be False for []
    for row in data[1:]:
         items = row.text.replace(u"kn","") # remove kn so items line up when unpacking
         time, ais_source, speed_km, lat, lon, course = items.split()[1:7]
         data = items.split()[1:7]
         text_file.write(str(data)+ ",Adams Challenge"+'\n')
```

Or use a `try/except` to catch the `ValueError`:

```
try:
    for row in aatable.findAll('tr')[1:]:
         items = row.text.replace(u"kn","") # remove kn so items line up when unpacking
         time, ais_source, speed_km, lat, lon, course = items.split()[1:7]
         data = items.split()[1:7]
         text_file.write(str(data)+ ",Adams Challenge"+'\n')
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: I still get an error `ValueError: need more than 4 values to unpack` on the line `time, ais_source, etc..`

Comment: @Dan, that has nothing to do with getting an empty list, that is because there are not 6 elements in `items.split()[1:7]`, have you tried printing `items.split()`?

Comment: so did I phrase the question wrong? I still want to skip the loop when the elements are empty

Comment: I would like it to proceed if there is not `data` and if there is I want it to write it to the text file.This worked up until I noticed that a spreadsheet was blank.

Comment: @Dan, my mistake, I just realised you are slicing so we need to catch a `ValueError` in the try/except. I edited